# csv.writer opens a new empty line, even with newline=''

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a code that gets a list of strings, and writes a csv file that containes all of these strings in one line.
here's what I got so far-

```
import csv
l = ['column1', 'column2',....]
with open('csvfile', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for x in range(1):
        writer.writerow(l)
```

I want the file to look like this:

```
column1 column2,...
```

but for some reason, it ends up looking like this:

```
column1 column2,...<\n>
```

I'm using windows and python 3.6.7.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A CSV file contains data in lines. That means there is a newline at the end of each record. You would you want a CSV file with two records to look like?

Comment: @zvone wdym? I understand the first two sentences, but I oly have one record in my file.

Comment: You always have only two values? Why are you using CSV writer for that? That in not CSV.

Comment: the values in the qustion are for example. I should change that- there can be an infinite amount of values in the list

Comment: The correct way to store that in CSV would be to have one column and as many row as there are values. Anyway, I don't really see what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My problem is that, while trying to put all values in one line, I'm writing unnecessary lines into the files. How can I not do that?

Comment: I don't get any "extra" lines; you should have a newline character at the end of each row you write -- that's how csv,writer works. However, your source posted has indentation issues and you should not name a variable `list`, which is the name of a builtin class. Don't use csv.writer if you want all your "rows" on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `csv.writter` you can just do it with Python's file handlers. Also dont use `list` as a variable name as its a keyword in Python.

```
list_columns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']

f = open('csvfile.csv', 'w')
for item in list_columns:
    f.write(item)
    f.write(' ')
    
f.close()
```

Output: column1 column2 column3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `csv.writer`, you will need to write to a string buffer and then do some editing:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

l = ['column1', 'column2']
out = StringIO('')
writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for x in range(4):
    writer.writerow(l)
# replace newlines with single space and get rid of carriage returns:
rows = out.getvalue().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
# final character is a space. Don't output:
with open('csvfile', 'w') as f:
    f.write(rows[0:-1])
```